# Just Grab image URL on json with php

Tags: php, json, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

I Have some Json respons like this.

```
{
    "status": "active",
    "city": "depok",
    "name": "Alternatif Cibubur",
    "lat": -6.376057,
    "thumbnail_html": "\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"cam-thumb\">\n  \n    \n      <a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">\n        <img src=\"https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg\" class=\"cam-thumb-img\">\n      </a>\n    \n  \n\n  <div class=\"cam-thumb-info\">\n    <p class=\"cam-name\"><a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">Alternatif Cibubur</a></p>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n\n",
    "lon": 106.900786,
    "id": 248,
    "description": "Kamera berada di jalan Alternatif Cibubur, arah menjauhi kamera menuju Cibubur Junction / Tol Jakarta, sebaliknya menuju Kranggan / Cileungsi / Bogor."
  }
```

as you can see, in the "thumbnail_html" path, there is an image url attached

```
{
    "status": "active",
    "city": "depok",
    "name": "Alternatif Cibubur",
    "lat": -6.376057,
    "thumbnail_html": "https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg",
    "lon": 106.900786,
    "id": 248,
    "description": "Kamera berada di jalan Alternatif Cibubur, arah menjauhi kamera menuju Cibubur Junction / Tol Jakarta, sebaliknya menuju Kranggan / Cileungsi / Bogor."
  }
```

I have actually tried using the str_replace and preg_replace statements, but the statement is too complicated and long, is there an easier way to retrieve the image URL?

Comment: Did you tried using regex with starting http and ending with .jpg`?

Comment: OK! i will try it, thanks Rick and kdoteu

Answer (score 1):

This regex can do work:

```
$subject = '\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"cam-thumb\">\n  \n    \n      <a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">\n        <img src=\"https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg\" class=\"cam-thumb-img\">\n      </a>\n    \n  \n\n  <div class=\"cam-thumb-info\">\n    <p class=\"cam-name\"><a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">Alternatif Cibubur</a></p>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n\n';
$matches = [];
preg_match('/(https?:\/\/.*\.(?:png|jpg))/i', $subject, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$string = '\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class="cam-thumb">\n  \n    \n      <a href="/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/">\n        <img src="https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg" class="cam-thumb-img">\n      </a>\n    \n  \n\n  <div class="cam-thumb-info">\n    <p class="cam-name"><a href="/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/">Alternatif Cibubur</a></p>\n 
</div>\n</div>\n\n\n';

preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $string, $match);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($match[0]); 
echo "</pre>";
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is [not recommended to parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

You could use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$data = <<<'DATA'
{
    "status": "active",
    "city": "depok",
    "name": "Alternatif Cibubur",
    "lat": -6.376057,
    "thumbnail_html": "\n\n\n\n\n\n<div class=\"cam-thumb\">\n  \n    \n      <a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">\n        <img src=\"https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg\" class=\"cam-thumb-img\">\n      </a>\n    \n  \n\n  <div class=\"cam-thumb-info\">\n    <p class=\"cam-name\"><a href=\"/cam/248/alternatif-cibubur/\">Alternatif Cibubur</a></p>\n  </div>\n</div>\n\n\n",
    "lon": 106.900786,
    "id": 248,
    "description": "Kamera berada di jalan Alternatif Cibubur, arah menjauhi kamera menuju Cibubur Junction / Tol Jakarta, sebaliknya menuju Kranggan / Cileungsi / Bogor."
  }
DATA;

$obj = json_decode($data);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($obj->thumbnail_html);
$obj = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute("src");
```

That would give you:

```
https://media.lewatmana.com/cam/tbicibubur/248/snapshot20180330_163142M-thumb.jpg
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/B6Lao)